# How to write $\Bbb S^4$ as manifold of revolution?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, rotations

Should I consider a 1-dimensional submanifold and revolve it to obtain a $n$-dimensional manifold or it should be of specific dimension?

For example I want to consider $\Bbb S^4$ as manifold of revolution. (More specifically I want to work out with 4-ellipsoid). What I should do? I should start with a semi-circle or a half-sphere or a half 3-sphere? in 3 dimensions, it is too classic that $x(t, \theta) = (a(t)\cos\theta, a(t)\sin\theta, b(t))$ for a curve $(a(t),b(t))$ embedded in $zy$-plane.

In next step I want to calculate its Riemann curvature tensor and related quantities.

Comment: "Rotation" works differently than three-dimensional intuition might suggest. It's not that there's a line axis, it's that there are _planes of rotation_. <> Given your last sentence, it sounds easier to parametrize the sphere stereographically, and then to do axis-scaling to get an ellipsoid.

Comment: You can write is as $\mathbb{S}^4\cong SO(5)/SO(4)$ with the short exact sequence $\{1\} \rightarrow SO(n) \stackrel{\iota}{\rightarrowtail} SO(n+1) \stackrel{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow} \mathbb{S}^n \rightarrow \{1\}$ given by $\iota(A)=\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\pi(B)=B(e_5).$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Woww, You meant replacing for example $z$ with $cz$? for constant positive $c$?

Comment: @MariusS.L.: sounds interesting. Can you expand it as answer? (is it cheeger technique?)

Comment: @C.F.G I have an elaborated example for $\mathbb{S}^3.$ You have two compact Lie groups $SO(5),SO(4)$, so you can consider their quotient topology. $\mathbb{S}^4$ is also the projective line over the quaternions, which is again a geometric interpretation.

Comment: Stereographic projection here means mapping $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ to$$\frac{(2x_1,2x_2,\dots,2x_n,x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2-1)}{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2+1}.$$This parametrizes the $n$-sphere with one point removed. The pullback of the Euclidean metric, i.e., the round metric on the sphere, is conformally flat in these coordinates.